# Populating Yii2 Model via behavior

Tags: php, yii2, behavior

I'm trying to assign a value to the property with behavior, but no matter what value I pass to `$this->owner->property` the model assigns this number "127" to the property and saves it. I can't figure out where this number comes from.

```
namespace common\behaviors;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\base\Behavior;

class MyBehavior extends Behavior
{
    public function events()
    {
        return [
            ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'test',
            ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'test',
        ];
    }

    public function test()
    {
        $this->owner->property = 444;
    }
}
```

If I populate this property htrough the web form on frontend the model saves correct value.
I added `property` to model's rules but that doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shame on me, I made so stupid mistake while creating SQL table :( I assigned tinyint type to `property` field, that's why it always saves 127 - the maximum allowed value for this type of field.